# Correct filtering and formatting using powershell and cmdlet Get-ACL

Tags: powershell, acl, powershell-4.0

I am not a powershell expert, but I have written some smaller scripts. Now working on a script which returns me the ACL of a folder and it children.

When I simply run get-acl I receive a lot of info, which I would like to filter our or skip. 
Basically I need:

- Full path, without Microsoft.Powershell.Core stuff..
- Group
- Access (don't need NT-Authori... users/groups)

So far I tried something like that:

```
get-childitem -recurse "$myfolder" | get-acl | select -PSPATH, Group, Access
```

but in this way I don't get the full names displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$group = acl.Access | ForEach-Object {$_.identityReference.value} 
$Access = acl.Access | ForEach-Object {$_.FileSystemRights}
```

Comment: yes that'S more or less what I did. Do you remember the command to display the full string of output? not just the first xx characters? also I shows still the microsoft.powershell stuff in the path.

Comment: which full string of Output and where did you get just the first few characters?

Comment: for the path for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Format-Table to output the data, you can use the -AutoSize property to force it to display all the information.

Regarding the full path you could either use:

```
get-childitem -recurse "$myfolder" | select FullName
```

or the messier option IMO:

```
$FullPath = $acl.path -replace ".*::"
```

The second option uses string manipulation to remove all text upto and including the "::"

Edit :-

This is the complete code I've used:

```
$Output = @()
$Path = "C:\SomePath"

$ChildItems = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $Path
foreach($ChildItem in $ChildItems)
{
    $FullPath = $ChildItem.FullName
    $acl = get-acl $FullPath
    $Access = $acl.Access

    foreach ($AccessObject in $Access)
    {
       $Group = $AccessObject.IdentityReference.value
       $Rights = $AccessObject.FileSystemRights

       $Line = New-Object PSObject
       $Line | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Path" -Value $FullPath
       $Line | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group" -Value $Group
       $Line | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Rights" -Value $Rights
       $Output += $Line
    }
}
$Output | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This is what I m using. Supply the list of folders in Path.txt file, which you need the ACLs for.

```
$erroractionpreference = "Continue"

$todaytime = Get-Date -format ddMMMyy_HH-mm

$OutPath = ".\ACL_" + $todayTime + ".txt"

$ACLS=get-content .\Path.txt

$Out=foreach ($ACL in $ACLS) 
{ 
    write-host $ACL -foregroundcolor green
    get-acl $ACL  | select @{Label="Path";Expression={echo $ACL}},@{Label="Access";Expression={$_.AccesstoString}} | ft -wrap -a 
}  

  echo $out >> $OutPath
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference (includes removing Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem:: ):

```
Get-ChildItem . -recurse | get-acl | Select-Object -Property @{Name='Path';Expression={Convert-Path $_.Path}},Group,AccessToString
```

Tough I recommend using Format-List or Out-Gridview:

```
Get-ChildItem . -recurse | get-acl | Select-Object -Property @{Name='Path';Expression={Convert-Path $_.Path}},Group,AccessToString | fl
Get-ChildItem . -recurse | get-acl | Select-Object -Property @{Name='Path';Expression={Convert-Path $_.Path}},Group,AccessToString | Out-GridView
```

I am searching for excluding or only show matching lines in the AccessToString property too, but have not yet found what I need.
Curiosity: What do you need "Group" for? "Owner" might make fore sense, from my point of view, so if you have a usage for "Group" I am curious to know.